# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE], express-session+redis Error

Tags: typescript, express, redis, express-session

I am developing with typescript + express

i want use Redis to Session Storage and i installed redis, connect-redis
and i code below

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import * as RedisStore from 'connect-redis';
...
const client = createClient({
    url: 'redis://default:qwer1234@localhost:6379',
});
client.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('redis success');
});
...
app.use(
    session({
        secret: env.COOKIE_SECRET!,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new redisSession({
            client: client,
        }),
    })
);
```

and i wrote code below to test redis

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const sess = req.session;
    if (sess.key) {
        res.send(sess.key);
    } else {
        res.send('FAIL');
    }
});
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const sess = req.session;
    const { username } = req.body;
    sess.key = username
    // add username and password validation logic here if you want.If user is authenticated send the response as success
    res.end('success');
});
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send('OK');
    });
});
```

But , I get the following error when saving a value to the session.
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array

because this error, the passport-local code that was previously implemented using memory storage does not work.
help me plz..

Comment: connect-redis version is 6

Comment: When I checked the console.log at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js line 61, it was confirmed that the arguments passed by connect-redis looked like an array.
Example 
[ 'sess: ~~~~' , '{"cookie":{cookieSetting...}, "key":"value"}', 'EX', ttl(number)]
I don't know which action to add to make it work exactly.

Comment: https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/336     
There is an issue 16 days ago.. Please check all of these errors when they appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue when using the current time-based redis 4.0 version, so you need to set `legacyMode: true` in the redis setting.

```js
const client = createClient({
    url: yourURL,
    legacyMode: true,
});
```